# Where was this photo taken (screensaver on LG Oled TV)?

Tags: identify-this, photography, lakes

[image]

Can someone please tell me where this picture of a church on an Alpine lake was taken?

Comment: Lake Bled, Slovenia, definitely worth a visit. The whole country actually!

Comment: I’ve actually started basing my trips on re-enacting the pictures from my LG tv screen savers..the photo a few before this one is Hallstatt Austria that we went to last year and are going to lake bled next month in June. Still need to figure out where the other 2 photos are in the screensavers lol

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like the Church of St Mary on [Lake Bled, Slovenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Bled).